# Rename column with the filter selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

How to rename the column name with the filter selection. I'm trying to automate the process so every time when filter is changed, I want the column name to be replaced by the filter selection. I need to declare the variable at the end to rename the column name based on the filter that is created at the beginning of the script. I want to replace the column name "Col1" with the filter name e.g. "General". How can I declare the filter name into renaming column

```
    df1 = df[(df.typ == 'GENERAL')]  #filter
     cols = df1.columns
     for col in cols:
        df1.rename({'Col1':'filter_name'}, axis=1, inplace =True) #assigning filter name to replace the column name.

 Current output:
 Col1   Col2   Col3
  10     20     30
  40     50     60

 Expected output:
  General   Col2   Col3
  10     20     30
  40     50     60
```

Comment: Do you only intend to rename the first column every time for each filter? If yes then you can just rename using the position of the column instead of the name in this manner `df1.rename(columns={ df1.columns[1]: "your value" }, inplace = True)`

Comment: What is the input DataFrame? What is `df.typ`?

Comment: @mozway dataframe type is object

Comment: @AfsanaKhan - Is it possible to call filter in "your place" value as you have suggested above?

Comment: OR is it possible to replace the column name with the value in the column??

Comment: @Josh that wasn't my question ;)

Comment: @Josh Yes I meant you can use your filter name in "your value"